# Creating mock stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, unit-testing, stored-procedures, mocking

Is there a simple way to automate/generate mocks or stubs based on sql stored procs?

The situation I am trying to cover is when changes are made to a proc in development, i.e. someone adds a required input parameter, I would then want the test that has not been updated with the required parameter to fail.

Comment: Personally I'd test against the actual stored proc (in a development/test environment). This would be an integration test (hitting the database), not a unit test, and might run daily.

Comment: Initially I think i was looking for a way to avoid doing this as an integration test by having mocks or stubs that are generated from the database...but then you are still interacting with the database each time you need to generate the stub/mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though less automated another approach would be to create a script that contains a set of execution statements for the stored procedures you are interested in.  By running these you could captured the ones that fail when there is a changed parameter.  You also could script out the exec store procedure bit in MS SQL

example

```
exec [DATABASE].dbo.[StoredProc] parameter1, parameter 2
```

This would not provide any mechanism for verifying results.  For a more comprehensive approach you might look at this example put together in the Simple-Talk newsletter that builds a test harness using c# and NUnit.

["Close those Loopholes - Testing Stored Procedures"](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/close-those-loopholes---testing-stored-procedures--/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write tests to verify the number of parameters your stored procedures accept.  This would be more of an integration type test than a pure unit test, but it would solve your issur.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate tests which call the stored procedures (perhaps with dummy variables) by inspecting [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933216%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

If you run [sp_recompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx) on such a test stored proc, it should fail to compile because of the incorrect number of parameters.