# Is there any way to mock a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have some example projects for client developers which should include calls to stored procedures in a SQL database but I don't want to have to include a database.

Is there anyway to add a provider which mocks the stored procedure?

My example apps all use the asp.net connectionStrings to configure the database connections. I presuming that mocking a DataSource and provider is what would be required!

Comment: It's common for developers to install SQL for their own dev purposes --the EXPRESS version is free.  Wouldn't this suffice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating mock stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888072/creating-mock-stored-procedures)

Comment: not a dupe, that refers to mocking a stored procedure, this one is trying to mock DataSource

Comment: SQLExpress would work just fine except I do't want the client developer to have to install the db. I'm just looking for a quick reusable solution for my examples where I can call SPs on, what the SP actually does is irrelevant for me.

Comment: Is it possible to write your own provider? Yes, MS does document how to do this.  Is it a reasonable amount of work?  Probably not, installing the SQL EXPRESS database would be an order of magnitude easier.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky - Ah, yes! Vote retracted :)